# mobile multiplatform development with native UI

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, native, multiplatform

i have developed an app, running on iphone and android, using phonegap and jquery mobile.
The combination of them is really great.

To support multi platform, I have also evaluated some other platforms too, but the problem that i have is that the UI does not feel native (and although not a problem for most apps performance cannot be compared with native).

The only solution so far giving acces to native UI seems to be monotouch.

Do you have any suggestions on platforms offering native ui at least on iphone and android, regardless of language used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now i will go with a mixed on js based on phonegap and native controls plugin which i will extend as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to have native UI response is to write native apps.

Comment: true :) on desktop the problem has not been solved even after 20 years

Answer (score 0):

The native UI is a puzzle indeed. You need read HIG firstly, cook UI with color and images to get close with system default ones. But if you are using PhoneGap thing, why do you even worry about it? Just rely on framework to get close the look and feel. Get your app really useful is more attractive than looking accustomed for user.

But it is important to adjust interactive design to avoid conflict. For example iOS navigation bar has return button in left most part, don't put it at right. And Android user will get disappoint if there is no response for long pressing or context menu key pressing.

Comment: for now i am letting the framework get as close as possible, jquery mobile does that to an extend. i was hoping there is a better way. i think monotouch might be the solution to that.